# Entity framework join with a subquery via linq syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to translate a sql query in linq sintax, but I'm having big trouble

This is my query in SQL

```
select * FROM dbo.ITEM item  inner join 
(
    select SUM([QTA_PRIMARY]) QtaTotale,
    TRADE_NUM,
    ORDER_NUM,
    ITEM_NUM
    from [dbo].[LOTTI]
    where FLAG_ATTIVO=1
    group by [TRADE_NUM],[ORDER_NUM],[ITEM_NUM]
) 
TotQtaLottiGroupByToi

on item.TRADE_NUM = TotQtaLottiGroupByToi.TRADE_NUM
and item.ORDER_NUM = TotQtaLottiGroupByToi.ORDER_NUM
and item.ITEM_NUM = TotQtaLottiGroupByToi.ITEM_NUM
where item.PRIMARY_QTA > TotQtaLottiGroupByToi.QtaTotale

and item.FLAG_ATTIVO=1
```

How can I translate into linq sintax?
This approach doesn't work

```
var res= from i in context.ITEM
                    join d in 
                    (
                         from l in context.LOTTI
                         group l by new { l.TRADE_NUM, l.ORDER_NUM, l.ITEM_NUM } into g
                         select new TotQtaByTOI()
                         {
                            TradeNum = g.Key.TRADE_NUM,
                            OrderNum = g.Key.ORDER_NUM,
                            ItemNum = g.Key.ITEM_NUM,
                            QtaTotale = g.Sum(oi => oi.QTA_PRIMARY)

                        }
                     )
                  on new { i.TRADE_NUM, i.ORDER_NUM, i.ITEM_NUM} equals new { d.TradeNum, d.OrderNum, d.ItemNum }
```

I get this error

```
The type of one of the expressions in the join cluase is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'
```

Can you help me with this query?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Anonymous Type comparison. You need to specify **matching property names** for your two anonymous type's properties (e.g. first, second, third)

I tried it out, here's an example: http://pastebin.com/hRj0CMzs

Comment: The error is solved, now i hope my damn query works!